# MySQL Summary price of order items in orders table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'phones' (
  phone_id    INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  price       FLOAT        NOT NULL,
  description TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'orders' (
  order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  date     DATE NOT NULL ,
  summary  FLOAT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'order_items' (
  phone_id INT,
  order_id INT,
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (phone_id) REFERENCES phones (phone_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (order_id)
);
```

How is it possible to set `summary` price of the whole order as a sum of phone prices * its quantity: `phones.price * order_items.quantity`. Is it possible at all? Or should I change my DB scheme in more appropriate way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it for all records use inner join.

```
update order
set summary = phones.price * order_items.quantity;
from order
inner join order_items
on order.order_id = order_items.order_id
inner join phones
on order_items.phone_id = phones.phone_id
```

Comment: Yea..Missed the column name..Edited now

Comment: thanks for your answer. But also can you tell me please is it a good practice at all to update row like this? Should I perform this after every insertion to the `order_items` table and if so, how? Or could I remove `summary` field and just make certain `SELECT` each time I want to get the summary price for order?

Comment: Yes do it like the last way. There is no need to run the update statement after every insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by joining the tables and updating orders summary as follows.

```
Update orders o
Inner join order_items oi On oi.order_id = o.order_id
Inner join phones p on p.phone_id = oi.phone_id
Set o.summary = p.prices * oi.quantity.
```

Comment: If you dont want to do update operation on each order insert. Find the summary while inserting only and insert it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but you need to summarize the prices in a subquery:

```
Update orders o left join
       (select oi.order_id, sum(p.prices * oi.quantity) as summary
        from order_items oi join
             phones p
             on p.phone_id = oi.phone_id
        group by oi.order_id
       ) oo
       on oo.order_id = o.order_id
    set o.summary = oo.summary;
```

Note:  The `left join` ensures that all orders will be updated.  If there are no order lines for the item, then `summary` will be set to `NULL`.  With an `inner join`, unmatched orders would not change the `summary` value.

Comment: Should I use this command each time I insert into `order_items` or `orders` table?

Comment: @VadZelenin . . . If you want the value to be the same consistently, then you would need a trigger.  I would advise you to just create a view with the logic above, so the values are calculated only when necessary.